# How to split a String on the basis of comma and pipe in java

Tags: java, regex

I have two String inputs where i have String interviewNames and timing there ,So they are in the format like

```
interviewNames = Deep Sen,Jeet Roy 
 timing = 00:00:00, 01:30:00 | 02:00:00, 02:00:00
```

i want those two Strings to be formatted like

```
Deep Sen -- 00:00:00, 01:30:00 | Jeet Roy --02:00:00, 02:00:00
```

So i have used

```
String formatNames [] = names.split(",");
        String formatTiming [] = timing.split("\\|");

        System.out.println("formatNames :"+formatNames.length);
        System.out.println("formatTiming :"+formatTiming.length);
        for(int i=0;i<formatNames.length;i++){
            System.out.println("formatTiming :"+formatNames[i]+","+formatTiming[i]);
        }
```

But it is not working and not meeting the requirements as well,can anyone help

Comment: What means "But it is not working"? what is the output you get?

Comment: formatTiming :Deep Sen,
formatTiming :Jeet Roy,0  this i am getting

Comment: For me it looks fine: `formatTiming :Deep Sen,00:00:00, 01:30:00 
formatTiming :Jeet Roy , 02:00:00, 02:00:00`

Comment: @lucifer `formatTiming :Deep Sen--00:00:00, 01:30:00 formatTiming :Jeet Roy --02:00:00, 02:00:00` it should done in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think you are doing the string split more or less alright. 
The problem is how you collect the data into an output string. 
I have provided a slight modification of you program and this prints out the output you desire.

```
    String formatNames [] = interviewNames.split(",");
    String formatTiming [] = timing.split("[|]");

    System.out.println("formatNames :"+formatNames.length);
    System.out.println("formatTiming :"+formatTiming.length);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<formatNames.length;i++){
        if (i>0) sb.append(" | ");
        sb.append(formatNames[i]+" -- "+formatTiming[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Now output looks like this

```
Deep Sen -- 00:00:00, 01:30:00  | Jeet Roy --  02:00:00, 02:00:00
```

Comment: Deep Sen -- 00:00:00, | Jeet Roy -- 01:30:0002:00:00,  where are the other part  ??

Comment: There was a slight error in the expression used for splitting timings. Corrected now

Answer (score 0):

Every thing is fine just edit below point

```
String formatTiming[] = timing.split(" \\| ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<formatNames.length;i++){
sb.append(formatNames[i]+" -- "+formatTiming[i]);
sb.append(" | ");  
}
String finalString = sb.substring(0,sb.length()-2);
```

Comment: how to get this Deep Sen -- 00:00:00, 01:30:00 | Jeet Roy --02:00:00, 02:00:00

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to StringBuilder  in this line  sb = sb.substring(0,sb.length()-1);

Comment: @lucifer wait few moment;

Comment: @lucifer check my updated answer and upvote and accept answer if it fullfill your requirement

Comment: @lucifer i am getting as expected output like `Deep Sen -- 00:00:00, 01:30:00 | Jeet Roy  -- 02:00:00, 02:00:00 ` is it correct now

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change the regex you are splitting the times on to `" | "`:

```
String formatTiming[] = timing.split(" \\| ");
```

To get the output you desire, use the following in your `for` loop:

```
System.out.println("formatTiming :" + formatNames[i] + " --" + formatTiming[i]);
```

Comment: `split(" | ")` means "split on a space or on a space".

Comment: @dave how toget the desired output  Deep Sen -- 00:00:00, 01:30:00 | Jeet Roy --02:00:00, 02:00:00??

Comment: <facepalm> left out the backslashes. How embarrassing.